# How to find variance for the given problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

A fair die with 4 sides is rolled 17 times. find the variance of the sum of the die rolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $X,Y$ are independent, then $\text{Var}[X+Y]=\text{Var}[X]+ \text{Var}[Y]$. Indeed, this is because $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and the cross terms vanish from the variance computation.

In particular, if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are $n$ i.i.d. die rolls, we have that $\text{Var}[X_1+\ldots+X_n]=n\text{Var}[X_1]=n (15/2 - 25/4) = 1.25n$

Comment: so  i need to just multiply 1.25 * 17 ?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: can you please explain me how comes (15/2) and (25/4) ?

Comment: 15/2 is the expectation of the square of the number on the die, and 25/4 is the squared expectation of the number on the die.